# 403 Error using PowerShell 5 as Kentico 8.2 REST client

Tags: rest, powershell, kentico

This REST request works when I load it directly in a browser in which I'm simultaneously logged into the Kentico 8.2 admin site:

```
https://www.example.com/rest/CMS.SettingsKey
```

Now, I need to return the same results using PowerShell 5. I tried various versions of the following:

```
$url = "https://www.example.com/rest/CMS.SettingsKey"
$httpMethod = "Get"
$credentialsBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("username:password")
$credentialsEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($credentialsBytes)
$headers = @{}
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic $($credentialsEncoded)")
$settings = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method $httpMethod -headers $headers)
Write-Host $settings
```

Note that "username" and "password" are the same credentials used to log into the admin site (when the REST request is working in the browser), and the user is a global admin.

The PS snippet gives me a 403 Forbidden error. I followed [this page](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Authenticating+REST+requests) and [this page](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Getting+data+using+REST), but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I enabled the REST service, but now I'm getting a 401 Unauthorized error. Again, the user is a global admin. I get the feeling the headers aren't being included in the request (or that there is a problem with the headers), because the same request works (from PowerShell) if I generate a hash and use hash parameter authentication instead of basic authentication. I tried using Fiddler a bit as suggested in comments, but I'm new to it, and I don't have time to dive in too deep right now.

Comment: I don't know anything about Kentico but as far REST requests go what you have here looks right.  Have you tried looking at the raw requests in Fiddler.  I would capture the browser request and the PowerShell request and compare the two to see what the difference is.

Comment: Make sure you have `
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` in your web.config as described [here](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Configuring+the+REST+service#ConfiguringtheRESTservice-ConfiguringtheRESTservice). Otherwise some URLs wouldn't work. However, in Kentico 9 even this won't help - seems to be a bug. In all versions prior to v9 it works just fine.

Comment: Submitted to our dev team. Let's see what they have to say to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested it using the latest hotfix versions (9.0.32 & 8.2.48) and it works just fine.

1. Make sure REST is enabled for the specific site (not only the global setting)
   [image: Enable REST for specific site]
2. Make sure you have `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` in your web.config as described [here](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Configuring+the+REST+service#ConfiguringtheRESTservice-ConfiguringtheRESTservice).

Comment: So if REST is enabled globally, and that value is inherited for the site, then should I leave it as inherited-enabled or change it manually to enabled? Or do you just mean to check the site-specific value to ensure it doesn't override the inherited value? I do have the `<modules...>` snippet in web.config.

Comment: Also, is it possible that the browser request is successful if the service is disabled for the site? Said another way, having performed the browser request successfully, is it correct to infer that the service is enabled?

Comment: Make sure the setting is enabled - either inherited or manually checked. The browser requests also worked for me even when the REST service was disabled for a specific site... so I guess you can't infer from that.

Comment: The service was not enabled. Please see edits to question. Note, we received an email this morning for a fix on the REST service security to disallow some requests from working even though the service is disabled? Coincidence?

Comment: No, that's not related. What happens if you open the URL in an anonymous browser window? Do you get 401 or are you being asked to enter credentials?

Comment: It asks for credentials.

Comment: Can you try to observe the requests with [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)? Compare the request sent via PowerShell to the one using anonymous browser window (with credentials filled in). What's the difference?

Comment: I was able to get this working for the table `CMS.SettingsKey`. The issue was a PowerShell issue, not really a Kentico issue. But at least I got confirmation about requests going through even though the service wasn't enabled, so I'll accept this answer.

Comment: It triggered me to write an article about Kentico & PowerShell... check it out: http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/three-ways-to-manage-data-in-kentico-using-powershell